# Pause a youtube video in a slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, youtube

I have a slideshow/slider containing images and videos from youtube.
Is it possible to pause the current youtube video if the next or prev button is pressed.
Also would i be able to auto play the clip when one comes back to the same slide?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. YouTube JavaScript Player API Reference is what you need https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#GettingStarted

Use `player.stopVideo()` method.

Comment: could we get a jsfiddle example?

Comment: https://google-developers.appspot.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo_b6ba68660c7e04dba8e862259d7e5ee2.frame you can see full example here.